# Moving a solution from Visual Studio 2010 to 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I was asked to build a solution for our client on our server which has 2010 Visual Studio and was not informed that the client has a 2008 Visual Studio on their server. Now I was asked to move my solution into their server and don't have an approval to upgrade them (silly isn't it?).
Does anyone know of a way to do this?
I know the other way around is quite simple but this is sort of a downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

It's a while ago I had to do this, but I think I only had to change the project file (not a solution-file);
Open the project files (*.vbproj or *.csproj) and downgrade the value in the attribute ToolsVersion (3.0 to 2.0?).

Or compare two (empty) projectfiles with each other to see the differences between VS2010 and VS2008.

Comment: Where in the file? :0

Comment: Directly in the root node: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has a facility for creating a project from source files. You could remove all of the non-source-code files from a copy of the working project then import those files into another version of Visual Studio to create a new solution. Many versions of Visual Studio have the command menu => **File** => **New** => **Project From Existing Code**. That command then shows a series of prompts to set up the new project. See [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/754c3hy7%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: If you mean the wonderful Add Solution option that I have in the 2010 version. It doesn't exist in 2008 :(